# How to get the description of a credentials object in a jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins Job defined to build and run a reporting application.
For manageability I am storing the DB connection info in Jenkins Credentials.
Using a `withCredentials` block I can get the username and password just fine, like so:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                  credentialsId   : credentials,
                  usernameVariable: 'db_user',
                  passwordVariable: 'db_password']])
{
  //send user:password:JDBCUrl to application here
}
```

However, we're storing the JDBC connection string in the Description.
So If I have the *credentialsId* how do I get the stored description?

Comment: hi , i have exactly the same requirements( database properties) . Did you find a way in order to retrieve the credential description ? Thx

Comment: @ulquiorra never did.  We just ended up hard-coding the connection string into the file and using the Jenkins Credentials for the User/Password only.